# In regex is it called lazy or non-greedy?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy, greedy, non-greedy, reluctant-quantifiers

I originally heard it as nongreedy. Then on references 'on the web' i saw it called as lazy. Which is it?

Comment: possibly argumentative as well... i mostly refer to it as nongreedy

Comment: How does it matter as long as the idea is conveyed?

Comment: Also see tag [tag:reluctant-quantifiers]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Non-greedy](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy), [ungreedy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), [reluctant](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html#difs), [minimal match](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Matching-repetitions), [lazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification) etc. all refer to the same concept. Which name to use is just a matter of taste.